# Using extension variables for plugin versions in gradle

Tags: gradle, plugins

I'm trying to use extension variables with Gradle to configure the versions of the plugins but it is not possible to use `apply from: versions.gradle` before the `plugins` block in gradle.

Is this possible to do?

Example of what I would like to do.

`versions.gradle`:

```
ext.libraries = [
    plugins: [
        coveralls: 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls'
    ]
]
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories{}
    dependencies{}
}

plugins {
    id libraries.plugins.coveralls versions 'versionhere'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it.

Applying a plugin with the `plugins` DSL has to be declared **as the first statement** in a Gradle build script. This behavior is mandatory.

You can check the [official guide:](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:binary_plugins)

> The plugins {} block must also be a top level statement in the buildscript. It cannot be nested inside another construct (e.g. an if-statement or for-loop)
>
> This requires that plugins be specified in a way that Gradle can easily and quickly extract, before executing the rest of the build script.

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I don't think there are alternatives